# How to determine the order of an alternating group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am asked to show that $A_8$ contains an element order of 15.  I understand from the theorem that the order is $n!/2$, but that yields 20160.  Thanks!

Comment: The order of an element is not the order of the group. Go back and take a look at the definition of the order of an element.

Answer (score 1):

Order of a group: number of elements.
Order of an element $x$ : minimum $n>0$ such that $x^n=Id$

So you have to find $x \in A_8 : x^{15} = Id, x^i \neq Id \quad \forall i<15$

Hint: a $n-cycle$ has order $n$, and a ($n$-cycle $\times$ m$-cycle$) has order $mcm(n,m)$ if they have no elements in common

Answer (score 0):

As user2357112 said in a comment, the order of a group $G$ is a different concept than the order of an element $g \in G$. The former is $\#G$ (the number of elements in $G$) while the latter is the smallest positive integer $n$ for which $g^n = e$ (the identity element in $G$).

So you need to find an element $g \in A_8$ such that $g^{15} = e$ and $g^n \neq e$ if $0 < n < 15$. How can this be done? Hint: What is the order of a cycle $(n_1,\ldots,n_t)$ in $S_n$? What about the product of two cycles?